# how to find out the duration time form Origin to Destination lattitude and longitude?

Tags: java, android

I am working on map for the first time , I have 2 place's lattitude and longitude. Now i want to find out the duration time in between them 
Any one who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Use this Api

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?    origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA
>   &waypoints=via:Charlestown,MA|via:Lexington,MA &departure_time=now
>   &key=YOUR_API_KEY

For more details refer [Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)